# ANSI codes in /etc/issue file

Tags: ssh, terminal, ansi

I have an /etc/issue file that contains some ANSI color codes on a Linux development board. When I connect from serial terminal, everything shows up perfectly. However, when I connect from SSH, the ESC character replaced by "\033" and not recognized by the receiving side, thereby preventing the ANSI code from taking effect. How can I fix that?

Comment: In `ssh` set properly the `TERM`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix that?

You don't. Most SSH clients (certainly OpenSSH) deliberately prevent ANSI codes from being output in the pre-login banner, so that an untrusted server could not potentially send harmful codes to the client – there's nothing you can do to change that from server side (that's kind of *the point*).

Suggestions:

1. Keep two copies of the banner, a fancy one in /etc/issue for console/serial logins and a plain monochrome banner in something like /etc/ssh/issue.net for SSH (the path is configurable).
2. Stop using the SSH banner for graphics in general. (Honestly, a large pre-connection banner gets *annoying* if one needs to SSH to a server frequently.) Move fancy logos to the post-login /etc/motd instead.

Comment: An untrusted and compromised server _can_ send arbitrary codes to the client to display, after (faking) a successful login, pretending that the data comes from motd or the user's shell. So I don't quite understand this point. If you have further data, could you please elaborate? I'd be happy to learn more about the issue (no pun intended). Terminal emulators have to be smart enough never to do arbitrarily stupid things upon receiving maliciously crafted data.

Comment: @egmont: Good question, I was pretty sure I had read about this being a security thing (not sure if it was the PuTTY commit log or the OpenSSH one), but now all I can track down is https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/7ba0ca7f6fa0c517822051412cf9f0e7b35304d4.

Comment: It's not too much :) Thanks anyway! :) [A year or two ago there was a bug discovered that the `scp` client would display raw filenames, including escape characters if any. That obviously lead to unexpected and confusing behavior. But `ssh` by its very nature has to allow control chars through, so it's a different story.]

Comment: @egmont: I _think_ I was remembering https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=commitdiff;h=530b6fed5dd32e9a751d440c6c2096485c31e7f7 and https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=commitdiff;h=b9c74e84dc0a547d994d04f708618470b1264316 which were preceded by https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=commitdiff;h=63a14f26f78097c3ee5aa8ea8160efbe3c62b5cd